# Serialize JSON object as per the condition using C# and Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing data from a database into JSON format using JSON.Net. But I am not able to get the result I expect.

I have to create JSON objects according to certain conditions like if my data for `datamap` is null then it should not be included in the JSON, and if it is not null then it should be included.

```
public class DatamapKey
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> DatamapKeyFields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}
public class DatamapKey1
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> DatamapKey1Fields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}
public class DatamapItem
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> DatamapItemFields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    public DatamapKey datamapKey { get; set; }
    public DatamapKey1 datamapKey1 { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<DatamapItem> datamapItems { get; set; }
}
```

Output JSON:

```
{
  "datamapItems": [
    {
      "datamapKey": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "datamapKey1": {},
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "datamapKey": {},
      "datamapKey1": {},
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "datamapKey": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "datamapKey1": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "datamapItems": [
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "datamapKey": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "datamapKey": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "datamapKey1": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think the `JsonPropertyAttribute` and its `NullValueHandling` is what you are looking for

Comment: Otherwise, if you requirement is to not serialize empty collections, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903151/how-to-omit-empty-collections-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: @Alex I have tried the above solution it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute causes the key-value pairs in the marked dictionary to be serialized as if they were properties of the class containing the dictionary.  This attribute is handled specially by Json.Net and thus the [`IgnoreEmptyEnumerablesResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903827/10263) suggested by @Alex in the comments will not have an effect on it.  But you could restructure your classes such that you don't need the attribute for `datamapKey` and `datamapKey1`, and that would allow the resolver to work on those dictionaries when they are empty, giving you the output you want.

```
public class DatamapItem
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> DatamapItemFields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> datamapKey { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> datamapKey1 { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<DatamapItem> datamapItems { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gw03gY

---

If you don't like that idea or don't want to modify your class structure, another option is to load your object instance into a `JObject` and use a recursive method to remove empty tokens from the hierarchy.  This approach is covered in detail in [How to omit/ignore/skip empty object literals in the produced JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36884902/10263).

Here is a demo fiddle showing that approach with your existing class structure: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jmNgYi

Comment: How can I achieve below  JSON based on the condition? {
  "datamapItems": [
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "datamapKey": {
      
      },
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    },
    {
      "paramName": "VE8321C",
      "datamapKey": {
        "module": 1,
        "id": 1391
      },
      "datamapKey1": {
       
      },
      "min": "0",
      "max": "40"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Based on what condition?

Comment: Condition is regarding the data of JSON for e.g if paramName==VE8321C then allow null data else remove the null data.